# How to run a console app as a windows service? I'm getting confused by the "ClickOnce" files MS gives by default (VS 2008, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, windows-services, console-application

This may seem a bit silly but I can't figure out where to start. I've found plenty of code online on how to do this, but I just don't know where to put it. I've created a console app that I'm trying to run in the background as a service (that will start when windows starts, close when windows closes etc..). I'm not sure what I should be doing to facilitate this though. Should I create a new project in the same solution? Or a new class in the same project? When I do create the service, how can I install it? Do I just publish it? I've found some code online saying I should have a .exe file but all I have is ClickOnce?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- What says [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984074%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  about windows service